# Как удалить sendmail из Debian 8?

Tags: bash, debian, sendmail

На сервере установлен `Exim4` и был еще установлен `Sendmail` в связи с чем возникли проблемы с отправкой почты.

Пытался удалить `Sendmail` такими командами `apt-get purge sendmail` и `apt-get remove sendmail`. 
Вроде как было написано что все Done..
Но.

```
~# service sendmail status
● sendmail.service - LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sendmail)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-03-31 18:08:07 MSK; 17min ago
  Process: 434 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sendmail start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sendmail.service
           └─583 sendmail: MTA: accepting connections
```

Сервер перезагружал.
Как почистить это дело?

Comment: виртуализация имеется? тогда обращайтесь с вопросами к хостеру.

Comment: ваш комментарий не в тему, вот честное слово.

Comment: к примеру, внутрь openvz-контейнера можно принудительно копировать те или иные файлы. именно с ситуацией, когда таким образом в контейнер был «впихнут» именно sendmail, я сталкивался на практике. и самое главное — удалить эти файлы, т.е., избавиться от sendmail-а, было невозможно.

Comment: виртуализация KVM и как бы никто хостеру не даст в данном случае что то пихать в мой сервер...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот и решение вопроса.

```
~# apt-get purge sendmail
~# apt-get purge sendmail-base
~# apt-get purge sendmail-cf
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем было удалять?

```
sudo systemctl disable --now sendmail
sudo systemctl mask sendmail
```

Comment: Ничего что вопросу 3 года? я уже не помню.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Для SO это нормально. Что-б не плодить сущностей, здесь принято ссылаться, уточнять или отвечать на старые вопросы.

Comment: Зачем костылять с масками, когда можно просто удалить? :)

Comment: @andreymal Тупо быстрее. ;-) И меньше на одну команду.

Comment: @Oxyd `apt purge -y sendmail*` :)

Comment: А, ну да.  Но кстати маскировать не так уж и обязательно, главное задизейблить ;-)